# How to use TextResponse, HtmlResponse and XmlResponse?

Tags: scrapy

I see there are several types of responses, but how do I signal Scrapy to return an HtmlResponse?

I think the goal would be to implement `def parse(self, response: HtmlResponse):`. Or is this supposed to be used some other way? Is there an usag example?

This is the example from Scrapy tutorial. How would I use HtmlResponse here instead of the default?

```
import scrapy


class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = [
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/',
            'https://quotes.toscrape.com/page/2/',
        ]
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = f'quotes-{page}.html'
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log(f'Saved file {filename}')
```

Comment: can you please add your existing code?

Comment: I added a minimum example. thanks!

Comment: `response.body` returns the HTML source. what's the issue?

Comment: How do you use XmlResponse?

Comment: `XmlResponse` inherits from `Response` class, you use it in the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scrapy tries to identify the type of response it gets and calls `parse` with a specific type. As far as I can tell, parse is never called with the base type `Response`. The Response identification is done in `scrapy/responsetypes.py by a sort of methods: mimetype, body, headers, etc.

Here's the mimetype identification map:

```
CLASSES = {
    'text/html': 'scrapy.http.HtmlResponse',
    'application/atom+xml': 'scrapy.http.XmlResponse',
    'application/rdf+xml': 'scrapy.http.XmlResponse',
    'application/rss+xml': 'scrapy.http.XmlResponse',
    'application/xhtml+xml': 'scrapy.http.HtmlResponse',
    'application/vnd.wap.xhtml+xml': 'scrapy.http.HtmlResponse',
    'application/xml': 'scrapy.http.XmlResponse',
    'application/json': 'scrapy.http.TextResponse',
    'application/x-json': 'scrapy.http.TextResponse',
    'application/json-amazonui-streaming': 'scrapy.http.TextResponse',
    'application/javascript': 'scrapy.http.TextResponse',
    'application/x-javascript': 'scrapy.http.TextResponse',
    'text/xml': 'scrapy.http.XmlResponse',
    'text/*': 'scrapy.http.TextResponse',
}
```

Since `parse` is called with one of the subclasses, devs have access to it directly in the `response` parameter. One way to use it is like this:

```
   def parse(self, response):
       if isinstance(response, HtmlResponse):
           ...
```